# How to refer to currently logged in users in swift using Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

This code shows the app's main view controller. We would like increment the currently logged in user's field value by 1. In the code below we are only able to do this by manually pasting "nDcAFLPpRuPXI9AOLkln" which we copied from fire base itself.

How do we automatically refer to the currently logged in user?
[snapchot of our firestore data tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoDMW.png)

```
@IBAction func bidButton(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let updateScore = db.collection("users").document("nDcAFLPpRuPXI9AOLkln")

    updateScore.updateData([
        "leaderboardscore": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
    ])
    
    db.collection("users").document("nDcAFLPpRuPXI9AOLkln")
        .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
          guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
            // there was an error
            print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
            return
          }
            
            // no data to show
            guard let data = document.data() else {
            print("Document data was empty.")
            return
          }
            self.leaderBoardScoreLabel.text = String("Current data: \(data)")
          //print("Current data: \(data)")
            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase Authentication, and asking how to get the currently signed in user, you should follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting a listener on the Auth object:
>
> ```
> handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> By using a listener, you ensure that the Auth object isn't in an
> intermediate state—such as initialization—when you get the current
> user.
>
> You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the currentUser
> property. If a user isn't signed in, currentUser is nil:
>
> ```
> if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
>   // User is signed in.
>   // ...
> } else {
>   // No user is signed in.
>   // ...
> }
> ```

I would strongly suggest learning how to use the listener, which will give you a callback every time the user is seen to sign in or out.

Once you have a [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User) object, you can use its uid property to get the string you're looking for:

```
let uid = user.uid
```